# Wald equality, expectation of a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_k=-1)=q \\
\mathbb{P}(X_k=1)=p=1-q$$

(two points distribution)

Let $\tau$ be the first moment when number of successes ($X_k=1$) is greater than number of failures ($X_k=-1$).

Calculate $\mathbb{E}\tau$ - the first moment when the sum of $X_n$, $n=1,2\dots$ is greater than zero.

My attempt:

I think we should use Wald equality. $\tau$ obviously is a stopping time. Also $\mathbb{E}|X_i|<\infty$ so:
$$\mathbb{E}\sum_{k=1}^\tau X_k=\mathbb{E}\tau \mathbb{E}X_i$$
I think that $\mathbb{E}\sum_{k=1}^\tau X_k = 1$ Am I correct here? Then $\mathbb{E}\tau=\frac{1}{p-q}$ Is that correct? And what if $p=1/2$ ?

Comment: To apply Wald one usually *assumes* that tau has finite expectation, hence what you proved is that E(tau) is either 1/(p-q) or infinite.

Comment: Two comments: $\tau$ can only be an odd number (do you see that?). So if $\tau = 2n+1$, then necessarily (although not sufficiently) $S_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} X_k= 0$, and so $S_{2n+1}= \sum_{k=1}^{\tau} X_k= 1$ by how $\tau$ is defined.

Comment: Yes, I see that. So my answer is correct, yes?

Comment: It appears so. But how would you deal with the case p=q?

Answer (score 1):

Let me sum up the comments in the question. your proof is not complete. I am not sure why you did not follow up on the comments.

As Did pointed out either $E(\tau)=\infty$ or $E(\tau)=\frac{1}{p-q}$ (note $E(\tau)<\infty$ is a condition for Wald's theorem to be satisfied. This is not clear in your case)

Note that when $p\leq 1/2$, this is negative/blows up so $E(\tau)=\infty$. This is not surprising

**What else needs doing:**

When $p > 1/2$, you need to show $E(\tau) <\infty$, then you can conclude $E(\tau)=\frac{1}{p-q}$, by Wald

**You need to show these results about Markov Chains**:

When $p>1/2$,  consider 1 as an absorbing state and the mc is positive recurrent with $E(\tau) <\infty$

Comment: We didn't have markov chains yet. Is there possibility not to use them?

Comment: There is--but since you are not following on my comments, I hesitate before forcing you hearing it...

Comment: @luka5z have you done martingales? i don't know an elementary way, tbh... maybe you should ask Did.

Comment: Did, I'm sorry I just didnt notice your comment. When I get home I'll try use it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did martingales.

Comment: Did, so what to do next?

Comment: @Did give him/me a hint please (without appealing to martingale theory, would be good)